# Magento Adminhtml date picker on custom page (non-form)

Tags: adminhtml, adminform, date

I'd like to add a date picker to a custom input field on a `.phtml`. file which is loaded by Block reference, i.e:

**Controller**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Title'); 
    $this->_setActiveMenu('namespace/module');
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/adminhtml_module'));
    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

**Block**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('namespace/page.phtml');
}
```

Which forwards to: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/namespace/page.phtml`.

Now that the forwarding is set up, I can design whichever kind of layout I'd like to on that page. i.e:

```
<div>Enter the date here:</div>
<input name='date' id='date'></input>
```

I'd like to know how I can reference **Magento's date picker** which it uses on form elements, i.e:

```
$fieldset->addField('date', 'date', array(
'name'               => 'date'
'label'              => Mage::helper('your_module_name')->__('Date'),
'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
'tabindex'           => 1,
'image'              => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
'format'             => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT) ,
'value'              => date( Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateStrFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                              strtotime('next weekday') )
));
```

- Source: [magento add calender date picker to custom form in admin (custom module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287046/magento-add-calender-date-picker-to-custom-form-in-admin-custom-module)

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So date fields are added using `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date`. What you could do would be to look into this file and check the function `getElementHtml` this is where the "magic" happens.

You should be able to call something like `new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date($config)` where `$config` is the array used on the call to `addElement`.

**Note this is untested but "should" work**

```
$element = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date(
    array(
        'name' => 'date',
        'label' => Mage::helper('your_module_name')->__('Date'),
        'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
        'tabindex' => 1,
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
        'value' => date(
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateStrFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
            strtotime('next weekday')
        )
    )
);
$element->setId('date');
$element->getElementHtml(); // this should now give you all the html that you could need
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me, but Adrian's expanded code did. But thanks for getting us going in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

$element should belong to Varien_Data_Form, so correct code is:

```
       $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));
        $element = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date(
            array(
                'name' => 'date',
                'label' => Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Date'),
                'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
                'tabindex' => 1,
                'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                'value' => date(
                    Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateStrFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                    strtotime('next weekday')
                )
            )
        );
        $element->setForm($form);
        $element->setId('date');
        return $element->getElementHtml();
```